# Is it possible for python to directly save and close an .xlsb file?

Tags: python, excel, save, xlsb

I have a .py process than opens an existing .xlsb file, reads existing data, undertakes my required analysis and writes results to various sheets on the same .xlsb.   This works very effectively, however I cannot see how to add code to automate the Save and Close of the .xlsb at the end of the .py.  My current solution is to do this using File/Save/Close manually in Excel after the .py completes.

I use open_xlsb with fairly well documented code to access and read the existing xlsb data, excerpt:

```
xlsbfilename = "full path to Myfile.xlsb"
with open_xlsb(xlsbfilename) as wb:
    with wb.get_sheet(xlsheet) as sheet:
       for row in sheet.rows():
           # do stuff #
```

The problem is there seems to be no Save and/or Close capability in this otherwise useful function, is there a way?   I am able to process the data with other Excel/python tools, e.g. I can use dataframes, numpy with this original .xlsb data, but whenever I try to use any Save or SaveAs with tools such as xlwings or pandas, I get error messages advising 'not available for my file type', excerpt such as:

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'This extension can
not be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the File name text box or
select a different file type by changing the Save as type.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

When I change the same code to use instead a test .xls rather than .xlsb, the code will work - it is simply that using .xlsb fails.   The obvious reply is - 'just change the file extension' but that is not the requirment here.   I am looking for any form of code that can add to a .py to Save and Close the open  .xlsb file.   It seems a simple requirement, maybe I am missing something simple and would be happy to learn that was the case?

Comment: You don't tell us what library "open_xlsb" comes from. If it's pyxlsb, then the answer is "no", there is a pending pull request to implement writing.

Comment: Apologies for that oversight in my post.  Yes I am using "from pyxlsb import open_workbook as open_xlsb"   Appreciate your feedback with this useful info.